# Подставить знак в алгоритм

Tags: c#

Есть достаточно сложный и длинный алгоритм который сравнивает знаачения, что-то вроде

```
if (x<z && y>z && a==b)
```

Так вот, есть ли способ передать в этот алгоритм знаки больше меньше равно, с формы, т.е. чтобы пользователь в интерфейсе мог выбрать x>y или x<y и подставить знак в алгоритм?

Comment: Есть миллион возможных методов. Начиная от булевого флага, указывающего направление сравнения, до кастомной реализации `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Я пока очень мало чего в этом понимаю, мне нужно что-то вроде "переменной знака" x переменная знака y которую я мог бы подставить извне

Comment: Ну, передавайте в алгоритм дополнительный флаг типа `bool`, проще не бывает. Устанавливайте значение в зависимости от ввода пользователя.

Comment: Так а как я потом из этого bool подставлю знак больше или меньше в выражение, это мне на каждый вариант знака придётся отдельное выражение составлять, а я как раз таки хочу этого избежать

Comment: А сколько у вас вариантов знака?

Comment: ну вот тут все знаки больше меньше мне нужно иметь возможность произвольно менять
if (me.hpp < MaxMyHp && me.hpp > MinMyHp && hpp(me.target) < MaxTargetHp && hpp(me.target) > MinTargetHp&& (me.getBuffs().Contains(MyBuff)||MyBuff==null)&&(me.target.getBuffs().Contains(EnemyBuff)||EnemyBuff==null))
            {

Comment: Как мне кажется, для этого надо написать особый класс, который бы выполнял такую функцию. Штатными средствами такое не реализовать.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, тогда `n` булевых параметров, и в коде

```
var cond1 =
    bool1 ? me.hpp < MaxMyHp && me.hpp > MinMyHp :
            me.hpp > MaxMyHp && me.hpp < MinMyHp;
var cond2 =
    bool2 ? hpp(me.target) < MaxTargetHp && hpp(me.target) > MinTargetHp :
            hpp(me.target) > MaxTargetHp && hpp(me.target) < MinTargetHp;

...
if (cond1 && cond2 && ...)
```

Или [так](http://bit.ly/1lvRVvT):

```
cond1 = me.hpp.Compare(MaxMyHp) // < 0 если меньше, 0 если равно, > 0 если больше
          * sign1 // 1 сохранит результат, -1 поменяет на противоположный
          > 0;
```